# Column div moving below the column div with largest height above

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, col

I am using PHP loop to create and display articles (as 'col' divs) from the MySQL database. If I use 3 "col-6" divs, the 3rd one moves below both the above divs. I want it to stay just close to the div above it(the first col-6 div in this case). How can I achieve this?

I have figured out that this is a problem with bootstrap columns. Also, I cannot use absolute positioning in this case.

````
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)){
    echo '<div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 blogColumn">';
        echo '<a class="articleLink" href="show.php?blogId=';echo $row['id'].'" target="_blank">';
            echo '<article>';
                echo '<header>';
                    if($row['file_id']==null){
                        echo '<img class="img-fluid rounded focus" src="https://i.ibb.co/ZNDm012/logo.jpg"/>';
                    } else{
                        $fileId=$row['file_id'];
                        $q="SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id='$fileId'";
                        $run_q=mysqli_query($con,$q) or die(mysqli_error($con));   
                        $res=mysqli_fetch_array($run_q);
                        $path="uploads/".$res['name'];
                        if($res['type']=='image'){     
                            echo '<img class="img-fluid rounded focus" src="'.$path.'"/>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<video class="articleVideo" src="'.$path.'" controls="controls">';
                            echo '</video>';
                        } }
                    echo '<h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2>';
                echo '</header>';
                echo '<p>'.substr($row['description'],0,100).'... Read More'.'</p>';
            echo '</article>';
        echo '</a>';
        echo '<hr/>';
    echo '</div>';}?>```
````

Comment: Why you not LEFT JOIN that filename? Break out of php, echo hell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full width of the page is defined by col-12.
So if you want to have 3 same width columns next to each other use col-md-4

```
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
<div class="col-md-4">...</div>
```

This will result in 3 equal width columns next to each other.

Comment: I do not want that. Suppose I have 3 divs with col-6. The first 2 divs are side by side but with different heights (say 200 and 300 px respectively). The 3rd div starts from below the 300px level, but I want it to begin below the 200px level. I hope you get what I want to convey.

Comment: for that purpose I would recommend using isotope.
here's an example:
https://www.bootply.com/exm4wDJMhX

Comment: You made my day. Thanks !